# Using the Flash Builder 4.5 iPhone Packager with the Pushbutton Game Engine

Tags: ios, flash-builder, game-engine

Has anyone used the iPhone Packager released with Flash Builder 4.5 to port a game built with the PushButton Game Engine to the iOS platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 2d action platformer (think lemmings meets sonic) currently running on PushButton Engine 1.1, on iPad 1G and iPod touch 3G and 4G. It runs extremely well using AIR 2.7.

(I should mention it also is running on Android and Playbook as well)

What's your question? :)